# set checkbox event checked periodic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkbox and I want when it
 checked work periodically every 10 sec.

```
$("#cctv_ch").change(function () {
      if (this.checked) {                                         
          alert("checked");                                   
      } 
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You want, when you tick the checkbox to execute a function every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **`setInterval()`** and jquery `is(':checked')` its check every 10s is checked or not

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var res = $("#cctv_ch").is(':checked');
if(res){
alert('checked')
}
else{

}
    
    },10000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cctv_ch">
```

Comment: i think he wants to say checked if it's checked if(res) { alert("checked"); }

Comment: @HuseynQuliyev i just show with `true` or`false` see my updated code.i was added snippet also

Comment: @LiviuBoboia you are right.but i was showing only Boolean type on before code